# IE8 Wordpress Website Compatibility Issue - Sidebar Showing on Bottom Of The Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, sidebar

I have this website http://www.basketballworkouttips.com/jump-manual-review/ and the problem is when viewing it in IE8 the sidebar gets pushed down to the bottom of the page. however, if I remove the review box from the page the side bar is showing ok.
I want to keep the review box but I don't want my side bar to be pushed down.

any idea how to fix this?

Here's the review box code

```
<div class="review">
  <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="">
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope="">
      <div class="ta_rating_container ta_box_right" style="width:240px;">
        <div id="ta_rating">
          <div>
            <div>Review of: 
              <span class="title item fn" itemprop="name">
                <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Affiliate Clicks', 'Jump Manual', '/jump-manual-review/-Review Box Link',, false]);" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.basketballworkouttips.com/go/jumpmanual" title="Jump Manual">Jump Manual</a>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <dl>
              <div class="clear_space"></div>
              <div class="hr"><hr /></div>
              <div>Reviewed by: 
                <span class="reviewer author byline vcard hcard">
                  <span class="author me fn" itemprop="author">Jesse Parker</span>
                </span>
              </div>
              <dl>
                <dt>Rating:</dt>
                <dd>
                  <div class="ta_rating result rating" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope="" itemprop="reviewRating">
                    <meta content="1" itemprop="worstRating">
                    <meta content="5" itemprop="ratingValue">
                    <meta content="5" itemprop="bestRating">
                    <div class="result" style="width:100%;" title="5">5</div>
                  </div>
                </dd>    
              </dl>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <div class="clear_space"></div>
              <div class="hr"><hr /></div>
              <h3>Summary:</h3>
              <div class="ta_description summary" itemprop="description">
                <p>
                  <span>The Jump Manual is an effective program that will help you increase your vertical leap. The program is easy to follow and provides one on one coaching from it's author + exclusive 60 day money back guarantee. if you're looking to increase your vertical this program is the best one to go for.
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rating_btn">
              <a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Affiliate Clicks', 'Jump Manual', '/jump-manual-review/-Review Box Button',, false]);" itemprop="url" class="ar_button ar_orange" href="http://www.basketballworkouttips.com/go/jumpmanual" title="Download Jump Manual" rel="nofollow">Download Jump Manual</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div itemprop="reviewBody">
        <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemscope="" itemprop="itemReviewed">
          <meta content="Jump Manual" itemprop="name">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a nesting issue. Your sidebar is within the same block element as your #content. Thusly floats will not work properly. FireFox and other browsers are most likely auto-correcting it, but IE8 is limited and does not give guess work to assist.

I would correct the issue by placing the #sidebar_wrap_right and placing it at the same level as #content. Then be sure to add a width to both in CSS and float the 2 divs left adding margin/padding as needed.

I also have never seen the tag below that is rendering, it is possible you have some invalid HTML and CSS as well.

```
<css3-container style="z-index: auto; position: absolute; direction: ltr; top: 5500px; left: 28px;">
```

Comment: Also I am seeing a excessive amounts of !important decorations made. These should only be used when 100% needed, and with the simplicity of the design this looks like your fighting against the per-defined styles than embracing them.